# graphql-Java typewiring for modified schema

Tags: graphql-java

I'm new to graphql. I have the following schema and Runtimewiring in My API. Below schema definition and data fetcher mapping in Runtimewiring works fine and i'm able to receive response from the API.

Working Schema :

```
    Schema {
query:Query
}
type Query{
prepaid(mobilenumbers:[String!]:[Prepaid]
postpaid(mobilenumbers:[String!]:[Postpaid]
}
type Prepaid{
customername:String
databalance:String
datavalidity:String
}
type Postpaid {
customername:String
databalance:String
amountdue:String
}

RunTime Wiring in my Java Code for DataFetchers Mapping :

return RuntimeWiring
 .newRuntimeWiring()
 .type("Query",
 .typeWiring -> typeWiring
 .dataFetcher("prepaid", getPrepaidDetails)
 .dataFetcher("postpaid", getPostpaidDetails)
)
.build()
;
```

i would like to modify the schema structure as below , and also i dont want any datafetcher implementation for "ServiceType". i just want "ServiceType" to be more of grouping alone and still want to achive this schema structure. 
But the above given RuntimeWiring does not for this scenario.

```
Modified Schema : 

    Schema {
query:Query
}
type Query{
ServiceType{
    prepaid(mobilenumbers:[String!]:[Prepaid]
    postpaid(mobilenumbers:[String!]:[Postpaid]
}
}
type Prepaid{
customername:String
databalance:String
datavalidity:String
}
type Postpaid {
customername:String
databalance:String
amountdue:String
}
```

Could you please suggest me how i should frame Runtime Wiring for the new schema, where i will not have data fetcher implementation for "ServiceType" in the above example.

Thanks